# how to do pagination to findOne method in mysql with node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

```
async hospitalTreatments(req, res, next) {
    var hospital_id = req.params.id;
    let hosp_treatments = await Hospitaldetails.findOne({
        attributes: ["hospital_id", "name"],
        where: { hospital_id: hospital_id },
    })
}
```

in my code in the method `findOne` getting multiple records.

How to do pagination for this?

Answer (score 0):

findOne function returns an object , not array of objects . you need to use **findAll()** . and for pagination try to use these filters:

```
{limit: page_size,
offset: offset_value}
```

example:

```
let page_size = 20;
let offset_value = req.params.page ? (req.params.page - 1) * page_size : 0;

let hosp_treatments = await Hospitaldetails.findAll({
        attributes: ["hospital_id", "name"],
        where: { hospital_id: hospital_id },
        limit: page_size,
        offset: offset_value,
    })
```

if you want to limit your result set {limit : 1}